# Replace string with array

Tags: javascript

I have strings which before processing (translate) have to be replaced, then after processing (translation done) replaced again.

```
 var str = 'BUY [[Manufacturer]] [[Name]] cheap or get other [[Categories]] from [[Storename]] <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Thousands of satisfied customers.';
```

So I first reference them in an array with:

```
var res = str.match(/\[\[.*?\]\]/gm);
```

then I replace them:

```
var placeholder_string = str.replace(/\[\[.*?\]\]/gm,"|");
```

then it will be processed (in this case translated).

Now I want to reverse back all placeholders "|" with the array `res`.

I know I can take a function in the replace argument from `replace()`, but please help me how to achieve that efficiently.

```
var revert_string = placeholder_string.replace("|", myfunc());
```

or is there a better way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a function replacement like you suggest, and for each match, retrieve (and remove) the next item from your saved matches.

`Array.shift()` does this nicely, and you don't need to keep track of indices or anything else.

```js
const str = 'BUY [[Manufacturer]] [[Name]] cheap or get other [[Categories]] from [[Storename]] <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Thousands of satisfied customers.';

const res = str.match(/\[\[.*?\]\]/gm);

// for demonstration purposes,
// uppercase the placeholder to show that the string has changed
// while maintaining the fields' positions afterwards
const placeholder_string = str.replace(/\[\[.*?\]\]/gm, "|").toUpperCase();

const revert_string = placeholder_string.replace(/\|/g, () => {
  return res.shift();
});

console.log(revert_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `split`, this also lets you use `|` in your text. This approach might also be faster (I think it should be).

```js
const str = '||BUY|| [[Manufacturer]] [[Name]] cheap or get other [[Categories]] from [[Storename]] <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Thousands of satisfied customers.';

// | here does not match the | character, its an or statement. So match "[[" or "]]"
const parts = str.split(/\[\[|\]\]/g) 
//get every odd part, so everything between "[[" and "]]"
let placeholders = parts.filter((_,i) => i%2==1)

//process, just as an example. Put your translation logic here
placeholders = placeholders.map((t, i) => `(Replacement for ${t})`)

//put them back together
const replaced = parts.map((p, i) => {
  if(i % 2 == 1) return placeholders[(i-1)/2];
  return p
});

const replacedStr = replaced.join('')

console.log(replacedStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter and increase the counter on each replace callback invocation

```js
var str = 'BUY [[Manufacturer]] [[Name]] cheap or get other [[Categories]] from [[Storename]] <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Thousands of satisfied customers.';

var res = str.match(/\[\[.*?\]\]/gm)

var placeholder_string = str.replace(/\[\[.*?\]\]/gm,"|").toLowerCase()


function stringRevert(str){
  let i = 0;
  return str.replace(/\|/g,()=> res[i++]);
}

var revert_string = stringRevert(placeholder_string)

console.log(revert_string)
```